# How to deal with PKG in sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, package, oracle-sqldeveloper

Usually I run scripts in sqldeveloper without any effort, but how I can run packages .PKG in databases?

Comment: What do you mean by "running a package"? Do you need to compile a package, or do you need to use ("call") functions and procedures from it?

Comment: I use a tool to store projects in databases, but now I need to store them with sqldeveloper. I dunno too much of it, I think that compile references to store them in databases

Comment: I need to compile the entire package but I dunno where is the option in sqldeveloper

Comment: @EdwardGuzmán Look for packages in left pane in connections tab under the schema that opens the code in new tab,click drop down on gear icon gives you two options to compile for debug or compile.Here is the [screen shot](https://prnt.sc/138up74) for reference

Comment: @Suresh the package in first glance isn't in the database, how I can make it to put it in the database and to register it

Comment: Just like scripts run in sql worksheet that creates a package

Answer (score 1):

This is "how":

- copy your package "text" (as far as I understood, it is now in some file on your disk) into SQL Developer
- click the "Run Script" in the toolbar (or press F9)
- if everything is OK (i.e. there are no errors in code), package specification and body will be compiled

  - now you can see it in Object Navigator, under the "Packages" node

[image]